# What is this metal M-shaped device for?

Tags: practice, equipment

I inherited this with a box of piano sheet music, some of which was for beginners, and vaguely recall seeing one ages ago at a music store. It’s about the right size for wearing like a pair of brass knuckles, but I have large hands and it’s slightly large even on me.

My best guess is a finger spreader for somehow enforcing good hand posture on a keyboard, but it seems rather unwieldy for that.

[image: Metal ‘m’ device]

Comment: My guess is that this is used to keep a book of sheet music open to the desired page.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's a clip that you use to hold music books open on the stand, like so:

[image: Music book clip]

Comment: Not only that, but it has the cool appearance of an octopus about to climb over the edge and dance across your score.

Comment: Works great until you want to turn the page in the middle of a performance...

Comment: Does it have a name?

Comment: Music Book Clip or Page Holder.

Comment: Nice, I'll have to try this out! I've always just had my books spiral bound, so they open flat and turn easily.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS: Indeed. But usually if you put the clip on the *last* page of the piece that's enough to keep the book open. (That said, spiral binding is indeed the way to go.)